# How to select a Pandas Datetime of a DatetimeIndex by position?

Tags: pandas

```
# Example pandas Dataframe
                            temp.value  temp.period
temp.time       
2020-08-21 08:00:00+00:00   21.666667   PT1H
2020-08-21 09:00:00+00:00   21.111111   PT3H
2020-08-21 12:00:00+00:00   21.666667   PT2H
```

My program receives data similar to the example above, where temperature values are valid for a variable number of hours, found in df['temp.period']. I resample the data into hourly data as so:

```
df.resample('H').pad()

                            temp.value  temp.period
temp.time       
2020-08-21 08:00:00+00:00   21.666667   PT1H
2020-08-21 09:00:00+00:00   21.111111   PT3H
2020-08-21 10:00:00+00:00   21.111111   PT3H
2020-08-21 11:00:00+00:00   21.111111   PT3H
2020-08-21 12:00:00+00:00   21.666667   PT4H
```

**The Overall Issue:** I need a way to resample the last row. In the above case, I need to add rows for 13:00:00, 14:00:00, and 15:00:00

**Current Strategy:** I parse the temp.period of the last row using regex,

```
period = int(re.search(r'\d+(?=H)', newdf.iloc[-1]['temp.period']).group())
print(period)

4
```

and then wish to add this number of hours to the latest hour in order to add a row with the final hour before resampling. Something to the tune of:

```
current_latest_hour = df.iloc[-1]['temp.time']
current_latest_hour_temp = df.iloc[-1]['temp.value']
final_hour = current_latest_hour + pd.Timedelta(hours=period)
df[final_hour] = current_latest_hour_temp

# Then Resample
```

The problem with this is that I just can't figure out a way to get `current_latest_hour`. The above doesn't work because ['temp.time'] is an index, not a column. iloc integers seem to only refer to columns.

While putting together this question I found a convoluted solution, but feel there must be a better way:
I tried pulling the index column first, with `times = df.index` but the return is a DatetimeIndex, not a series, so I can't use iloc. So then I change it to a series before using iloc with `time = test.to_series().iloc[-1]`. Now I have the number I need and can get the final hour with `time + pd.Timedelta(hours=period)`. However, it still seems to me there would be a better way, either for the overall problem or this little issue, and I still don't fully understand why/whether you cannot more easily select a value from an index, whether DatetimeIndex or otherwise, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: try: df.reset_index()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses `.extract()` to pull the integer out of period, and keeps date as an index.  First, create the data frame:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''date                            value  period
2020-08-21 08:00:00+00:00   21.666667   PT1H
2020-08-21 09:00:00+00:00   21.111111   PT3H
2020-08-21 12:00:00+00:00   21.666667   PT2H
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), 
                 sep='\s\s+', 
                 engine='python', 
                 index_col='date', 
                 parse_dates=True)

# extract numeric part of period (PT1H -> 1)
df['offset'] = df['period'].str.extract(r'\w+(\d+)\w+').astype(int)

print(df)
                               value period  offset
date                                               
2020-08-21 08:00:00+00:00  21.666667   PT1H       1
2020-08-21 09:00:00+00:00  21.111111   PT3H       3
2020-08-21 12:00:00+00:00  21.666667   PT2H       2
```

Get the latest value:

```
print( df['value'].iloc[-1] )
21.666667
```

And get the last timestamp:

```
print( df.index[-1] )
2020-08-21 12:00:00+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your sample data.  temp.time is not a `DatetimeIndex`.  However a `reset_index()` before `iloc[-1]` allows you to access everything.

```
import re

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                            temp.value  temp.period
temp.time       
2020-08-21 08:00:00+00:00   21.666667   PT1H
2020-08-21 09:00:00+00:00   21.111111   PT3H
2020-08-21 12:00:00+00:00   21.666667   PT2H"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

dflast = df.iloc[-1].reset_index()
dflast.columns
lr = df.reset_index().iloc[-1].to_dict()
final_hour = pd.to_datetime(lr["temp.time"]) + \
                pd.Timedelta(hours=int(re.search(r'\d+(?=H)', lr["temp.period"]).group()))
df[final_hour] = lr["temp.value"]

print(df.to_string())
```

**output**

```
                           temp.value temp.period  2020-08-21 14:00:00+00:00
temp.time                                                                   
2020-08-21 08:00:00+00:00   21.666667        PT1H                  21.666667
2020-08-21 09:00:00+00:00   21.111111        PT3H                  21.666667
2020-08-21 12:00:00+00:00   21.666667        PT2H                  21.666667
```